# Sum div when parent div has more than three child div

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML structure with `div` elements. I want to find the sum of the values in the children `div`s of each parent `div`, but only if the parent has at least three children.

This is what I tried, but it gets the sum from every div:

```js
var sum = 0;
$("div > div > div").each(function () {
    sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
      <!-- want to calculate this --->
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- don't want to calculate this --->
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- want to calculate this --->
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in the example above, I’d print the answer 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for each of those divs, if it's parent has more than 3 children:

```js
var sum = 0;
$("div > div > div").each(function () {
  if($(this).parent().children('div').length >3){
    sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    }
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
      <!-- want to calculate this --->
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- don't want to calculate this --->
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- want to calculate this --->
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to wait 7 more minutes before i can accept your answer and i can't upvote either :S

Comment: You can make it even more specific with `.children('div')` - that way other tags that happen to be in there don't count.  Otherwise I was about to post this exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

give the parent divs a class, let's call it `.parent` for now:

```
var sum = 0;
$(".parent").each(function () {
    if($(this).children('div').length>3){
        $(this).children('div').each(function(){
           sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10); 
        });
    }
});

console.log(sum);
```